# Material altered on asset Library linked (Transmission)

Tags: materials, asset, library-overrides

[image]

[image]

When I put my character file in the asset library and use it, the eye material (mostly the cause of the transmission shader) changes. I am trying to figure out if there was a way to at least keep the material constant, if there isn't a possible way I am fine with editing the eye material.